# Difference between angular.json and package.json in angular project

Tags: angular

What is the difference between `angular.JSON` and `package.JSON` in an angular project?

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config

Answer (score 3):

`package.json` is not related to angular's ecosystem. It's npm's ecosystem and its responsible for keeping meta data about pacakges/libraries you use as your dependency.
https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/configuring-npm/package-json

`angular.json` is related to angular ecosystem, its responsible for your angular app configuration. You can learn more from official angular docs.

https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config

Answer (score 2):

Package.JSON holds all of the “npm” packages installed for the project.
Angular.JSON holds the configuration for the project.